# Unrecognized part 'mnc1' in configuration mcc219-mnc1 on android studio

Tags: android

> Task :mergePlayDebugResources FAILED
> Execution failed for task ':mergePlayDebugResources'.
> Unrecognized part 'mnc1' in configuration mcc219-mnc1

While upgrading from gradle 3.6.3 to 7.4.1 getting the above error
android studio: android-studio-chipmunk
AGP:7.1.1
Gradle: 7.4.1

Comment: Anyone who have done gradle updating undergone same scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In project there is xml file which was not named properly. Renamed that file and my issues is solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try to create new empty app with this version of Gradle (7.4.1) and be sure that app can be opened successfully. So you will see the build.gradle file configurations, copy them into your project and try to invalidate cashes and restart.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, done the same but still the same issue.